# SQL Left join not displaying all rows from left

Tags: mysql, left-join

So a rough structure of my two tables concered is as follows:

```
Table one: Services
services.id
services.name

Table two: Orders
orders.id
orders.item
orders.service
```

Table one contains a list of services. And table two is a list of orders. I am trying to generate a list of all orders for services from table two (orders) but also include (Zero) the services that haven't been ordered. I'm aware that that's where the LEFT JOIN comes but it doesn't seem to be working at all. It displays most of the services but there's one or two records (from services) not being displayed. Here's the query i'm using so far..

Any guidance at all is much appreciated, thanks!

```
select services.name,count(orders.service)
from services
LEFT JOIN orders ON services.id=orders.service
WHERE item IN (1,2,3,4)
group by statuses.service;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original selection is fine and should allow all records from the services table through.  However you're then restricting this by your `where` clause.  If there was no join for a specific row, `item` will have a `NULL` in it which your `WHERE` clause is filtering out.

```
SELECT services.name
   ,COUNT(orders.service)
FROM services
LEFT JOIN orders ON services.id = orders.service
WHERE item IS NULL
    OR item IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4 )
GROUP BY statuses.service;
```

Forgive me if slightly wrong, I'm coming from SQL Server background.

Comment: It would probably be better to move the IN clause into the join condition: `ON services.id = orders.service AND item IN (...)`

Comment: It makes more sense to put it in the join condition, since where item is null ... leads to wrong counts (it also counts items not in (1,2,3,4))

Comment: as much as i understand from this http://www.wellho.net/mouth/158_MySQL-LEFT-JOIN-and-RIGHT-JOIN-INNER-JOIN-and-OUTER-JOIN.html example left join in mysql can bring the null values, too. so writing "is null" is not a requirement i guess.

Comment: True, but that only holds for the original selection set from the two tables.  The `WHERE` clause is then applied afterwards which will remove them again.  @Frank's solution is cleaner anyway.

Comment: @Emre: In principle, that's correct - a left join brings in all the rows from the services table, regardless of the number of matching rows in the orders table.
In this case, however, this doesn't work, since the where condition explicitly removes the rows whose item is not in (1,2,3,4), especially all the rows where item IS NULL.
So, if you add "where item IS NULL" to the query as suggested by Sir Crispalot, you get all rows from the services table that have either no order at all or at least one order with item in (1,2,3,4)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I believe you've got a typo - statuses.service should be services.name, right?

Since item is a column from the orders table, you should put it in the join condition:

```
select services.name,count(orders.service)  
from services  
LEFT JOIN orders ON services.id=orders.service and services.item IN (1,2,3,4)  
group by statuses.service;
```

Otherwise, you filter out the services without orders or whose orders only have items not in (1,2,3,4).

Kind regards, Frank